# how do i return the response back to caller asynchronously using a final callback dispatched from on_read handler?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I need to expose an async REST api for c++ clients, that internally uses boost::beast for sending REST requests / receiving responses.

The starting point is http_client_async.cpp example.

Now the client will pass a callback function using this async api, that needs to be called at the end of the REST operation from the on_read() handler[http_client_async.cpp], passing the full response back to the caller.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but is there any way to invoke thie _callback through asio's io_context? I would like to call this callback in async fashion since this callback , which is provided by the user could block, and thus block the io_context's thread aswell? Similar to the way the other handlers like the on_read(), on_write() etc are scheduled in the io_context?

Yes. What you're after is the async_result protocol. I have some examples of that in other answers (e.g. [How can I get a future from boost::asio::post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950679/how-can-i-get-a-future-from-boostasiopost/49955899#49955899)).

Here's the building blocks:

### Store a handler

In your "session" (let's rename it `http_request_op` and hide it in some detail namespace), you want to remember a completion handler.

Don't worry, nobody **has** to come up with the such a handler. We will add an *initiaing function* `async_http_request` that will make it for you.

The end-user might use a future or a coroutine (yield_context). Of course, they **can** supply a plain vanilla callback if they prefer.

```
using Response = http::response<http::string_body>;

template <typename Handler>
class http_request_op : public std::enable_shared_from_this<http_request_op<Handler> > {
    // ...
    Response res_;
    Handler handler_;

    // ...
  public:

    template <typename Executor>
    explicit http_request_op(Executor ex, Handler handler)
        : resolver_(ex),
        stream_(ex),
        handler_(std::move(handler))
    { }
```

Now in your final step you invoke that `handler_`. To keep it simple I made the `fail` helper into a member function and called it `complete`:

```
void complete(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) {
    if (ec && what) {
        // TODO: A better idea would to make a custom `Response` type that
        // has room for "fail stage"
        res_.reason(what);
    }
    post(stream_.get_executor(), [this, ec, self=this->shared_from_this()] {
            handler_(ec, std::move(res_));
        });
}
```

All the places that check `ec` and used `fail` before now call `complete` with the same `ec`. In addition, in `on_read` we add an *unconditional* completion:

```
void on_read(beast::error_code ec, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
    if (ec)
        return complete(ec, "read");
    stream_.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

    // unconditional complete here
    return complete(ec, "shutdown");
}
```

### Initiating function (`async_http_request`)

```
template <typename Context, typename Token>
auto async_http_request(Context& ctx, beast::string_view host, beast::string_view port, beast::string_view target, int version, Token&& token) {
    using result_type = typename net::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(beast::error_code, Response)>;
    using handler_type = typename result_type::completion_handler_type;
    handler_type handler(std::forward<Token>(token));
    result_type result(handler);

    std::make_shared<detail::http_request_op<handler_type> >
        (make_strand(ctx), std::move(handler))
            ->start(host, port, target, version);

    return result.get();
}
```

You see this creates an async result, which crafts a "handler" from the token passed, kicks of the `http_request_op` and returns the async result.

What is returned depends on what token is passed. See the usages:

### Usage

I'll show various ways in which end-users can choose to use this `async_http_request` initiating function:

#### Using a future

```
auto future = async_http_request(ioc.get_executor(), host, port, target, version, net::use_future);
ioc.run();

std::cout << future.get() << "\n";
```

The return type is `std::future<Response>`.

> The creation of the promise and setting the return value/exception information is magically handled by Asio.

#### Using a coroutine/yield context:

```
net::spawn(ioc, [&ioc,args](net::yield_context yield) {
    try {
        auto host   = args[0];
        auto port   = args[1];
        auto target = args[2];
        int version = args[3]=="1.0"? 10 : 11;

        Response res = async_http_request(
                ioc,
                host, port, target, version,
                yield);

        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        // no way to get at response here
        std::cout << "There was an error: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
    }
});

ioc.run();
```

The return type is just `Response` here. Note that exceptions are raised if an error condition is reported. Alternatively, pass an error_code variable:

```
        beast::error_code ec;
        Response res = async_http_request(
                ioc,
                host, port, target, version,
                yield[ec]);

        std::cout << ec.message() << "\n" << res << std::endl;
```

#### Still using a callback

```
/*void*/ async_http_request(ioc, host, port, target, version, 
    [](beast::error_code ec, Response const& res) {
        std::cout << ec.message() << "\b" << res << "\n";
    });
```

The return value ends up being simply `void`.

### Full Demo Code

No live demo because no online compiler supports network requests and also it exceeds compilation limits (e.g. [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5aed9fd6e1a1ecec))

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>

#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace net = boost::asio;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

using Response = http::response<http::string_body>;

namespace detail {
    template <typename Handler>
    class http_request_op : public std::enable_shared_from_this<http_request_op<Handler> > {
        tcp::resolver resolver_;
        beast::tcp_stream stream_;
        beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
        http::request<http::empty_body> req_;
        Response res_;
        Handler handler_;

        template <typename F>
        auto bind(F ptmf) { return beast::bind_front_handler(ptmf, this->shared_from_this()); }

        void complete(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) {
            if (ec && what) {
                // TODO: A better idea would to make a custom `Response` type that
                // has room for "fail stage"
                res_.reason(what);
            }
            post(stream_.get_executor(), [this, ec, self=this->shared_from_this()] {
                    handler_(ec, std::move(res_));
                });
        }
      public:
        template <typename Executor>
        explicit http_request_op(Executor ex, Handler handler)
          : resolver_(ex),
            stream_(ex),
            handler_(std::move(handler))
        { }

        void start(beast::string_view host, beast::string_view port, beast::string_view target, int version) {
            req_.version(version);
            req_.method(http::verb::get);
            req_.target(target);
            req_.set(http::field::host, host);
            req_.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
            resolver_.async_resolve(host.to_string(), port.to_string(), 
                bind_executor(stream_.get_executor(), bind(&http_request_op::on_resolve)));
        }

      private:
        void on_resolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results) {
            if (ec)
                return complete(ec, "resolve");
            stream_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
            stream_.async_connect(results, bind(&http_request_op::on_connect));
        }

        void on_connect(beast::error_code const& ec, tcp::endpoint const&) {
            if (ec)
                return complete(ec, "connect");
            stream_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
            http::async_write(stream_, req_, bind(&http_request_op::on_write));
        }

        void on_read(beast::error_code ec, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
            if (ec)
                return complete(ec, "read");
            stream_.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

            // unconditional complete here
            return complete(ec, "shutdown");
        }

        void on_write(beast::error_code ec, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
            if (ec)
                return complete(ec, "write");
            http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, res_, bind(&http_request_op::on_read));
        }
    };
}

template <typename Context, typename Token>
auto async_http_request(Context& ctx, beast::string_view host, beast::string_view port, beast::string_view target, int version, Token&& token) {
    using result_type = typename net::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(beast::error_code, Response)>;
    using handler_type = typename result_type::completion_handler_type;
    handler_type handler(std::forward<Token>(token));
    result_type result(handler);

    std::make_shared<detail::http_request_op<handler_type> >
        (make_strand(ctx), std::move(handler))
            ->start(host, port, target, version);

    return result.get();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<beast::string_view> args{argv+1, argv+argc};
    if (args.size() == 3) args.push_back("1.1");

    if (args.size() != 4) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: http-client-async <host> <port> <target> [<HTTP "
                     "version: 1.0 or 1.1(default)>]\n"
                  << "Example:\n"
                  << "    http-client-async www.example.com 80 /\n"
                  << "    http-client-async www.example.com 80 / 1.0\n";
        return 255;
    }

    auto host   = args[0];
    auto port   = args[1];
    auto target = args[2];
    int version = args[3]=="1.0"? 10 : 11;

    net::io_context ioc;

    net::spawn(ioc, [=,&ioc](net::yield_context yield) {
        try {
            Response res = async_http_request(
                    ioc,
                    host, port, target, version,
                    yield);

            std::cout << "From coro (try/catch): " << res.reason() << std::endl;
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
            // no way to get at response here
            std::cout << "coro exception: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
        }
    });

    net::spawn(ioc, [=,&ioc](net::yield_context yield) {
        beast::error_code ec;
        Response res = async_http_request(
                ioc,
                host, port, target, version,
                yield[ec]);

        std::cout << "From coro: " << ec.message() << ", " << res.reason() << "\n";
    });

    /*void*/ async_http_request(ioc, host, port, target, version, 
        [](beast::error_code ec, Response const& res) {
            std::cout << "From callback: " << ec.message() << ", " << res.reason() << "\n";
        });

    auto future = async_http_request(ioc, host, port, target, version, net::use_future);

    ioc.run();
    try {
        std::cout << "From future: " << future.get().reason() << "\n";
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        std::cout << "future exception: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output for a successful and failing requests:

```
$ ./sotest www.example.com 80 / 1.1
From callback: Success, OK
From coro: Success, OK
From coro (try/catch): OK
From future: OK

$ ./sotest www.example.com 81 / 1.1
From callback: The socket was closed due to a timeout, connect
coro exception: The socket was closed due to a timeout
From coro: The socket was closed due to a timeout, connect
From future: future exception: The socket was closed due to a timeout

$ ./sotest www.example.cough 80 / 1.1
From callback: Host not found (authoritative), resolve
coro exception: Host not found (authoritative)
From coro: Host not found (authoritative), resolve
From future: future exception: Host not found (authoritative)

$ ./sotest www.example.com rhubarb / 1.1
From callback: Service not found, resolve
coro exception: Service not found
From coro: Service not found, resolve
From future: future exception: Service not found
```

Note that the timeout example of course runs in ~30s total, because everything runs asynchronously.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I did stumble on your other answer that you linked here. Came to know about this way through your inputs from that answer. There is a similar example in official boost sources called echo_op.cpp, but thanks for your response here thats customised for http_client_async.cpp :)

Comment: I know this solution is a little heavy, and is actually complete as its flexible on the handler the client uses. I just want to know what more advantages does this approach have over just putting up a net::post(m_ioc.get_executor(),beast::bind_handler(m_cb, ec,http_resp{})); at the places where i need to notify the user from within the individual async_handlers like on_read, on_connect etc? This call also schedules an async callback on the io_context::run()'s thread. So does it seem like a good enough solution on the cheap?

Comment: Better control (over execution/allocation) and composition. Also, I fail to see how it's much heavier. I believe the difference is ~6 lines of code in the initiating function?

Comment: From your SO profile, https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/ i would like to follow here, but this ends up in a 404.

Comment: Funny you mention that. That's [the second time in two days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138176/how-to-find-two-points-that-form-closest-distance-between-two-rectangles/62143399#comment109938728_62143399) - I didn't think anyone ever looks in bios. I'll remove the link or somehow add a note to indicate that the site sank... :(

Comment: by heavier i meant in the grasping sense ,not lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/async/http_client_async.cpp) as you call out:

Modify `session` constructor to take a callback that accepts an http status integer and a body string.

```
typedef std::function<void(unsigned int, const std::string&)> CALLBACK;

CALLBACK callback_;

explicit
session(net::io_context& ioc, CALLBACK& callback)
    : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
    , stream_(net::make_strand(ioc))
    , _callback(callback)
{
}
```

Modify `session::on_read` to invoke the callback.

```
void
on_read(
    beast::error_code ec,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{

    if(ec)
    {
        _callback(0, "");
    }
    else
    {
        _callback(_res.result_int(), _res.body());
    }
}
```

Comment: but is there any way to invoke thie _callback through asio's io_context? I would like to call this callback in async fashion since this callback , which is provided by the user could block, and thus block the io_context's thread aswell? Similar to the way the other handlers like the on_read(), on_write() etc are scheduled in the io_context?

Comment: The pattern would be to create a initiating function.