# Scale multiple geometries in boost geometry

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, boost-geometry

I know how to scale a single geometry in boost (e.g. using matrix_transformer [1]). But let's say I have polygons, points and lines.

Now my problem is the following: I'm calculating a single bounding box of all geometries, and present that bbox to a user in order to allow him to resize that bbox. Afterwards, I want to scale and translate all geometries within that bbox accordingly.

Can this be done with boost::geometry?

[1] [Polygon transformation in Boost.Geometry in C++: Translation, Rotation, Reflection around a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730299/polygon-transformation-in-boost-geometry-in-c-translation-rotation-reflecti)

Comment: Yes. You can apply the same matrix transformation to all objects. What is the question?